# sorting an arraylist of string with numerical values in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need to sort an arraylist of string which contains numerical values.
The arraylist is as follows

```
A\B=5\C=56,
A\B=2\C=1,
A\B=2\C=25,
D\E=1,
D\E=3\F=5,
D\E=3\F=4 
etc...
```

Sorting order I require is :

```
A\B=2\C=1
A\B=2\C=25
A\B=5\C=56
D\E=1
D\E=3\F=4
D\E=3\F=5
```

Comment: What does A\B=5\C=56 mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to implement a `Comparator<String>` where it can determine the greater-than/less-than behavior of *any two* of your strings.

`Then, you can sort it via Collections.sort(list, myNewComparator);`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("A\\B=5\\C=56");
        list.add("A\\B=2\\C=1");
        list.add("A\\B=2\\C=25");
        list.add("D\\E=1");
        list.add("D\\E=3\\F=5");
        list.add("D\\E=3\\F=4");
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
```

If you want to custom your sorting then try for  go for the previous answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), but I think, you have to write your own Comparator.